# list view just display in the second activity the last row

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-listview

i a creating android application  using json parser to get data from web and display it in listview.
after the user select a row the system display the details in a second activity using the intent.

**the problem is that whatever the user select the system display the last row in the list view.**

can anyone  help me to fix this problem ?

[image]

[image: here i did not chose the last row]

## JsonActivityHttpClient

```
package com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class JsonActivityHttpClient extends ListActivity {

    // ***from JsonHandlerClass****//
    JSONArray PostalCodes;
    List<String> result;

    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONObject postalCode;

    private static final String PLACE_NAME_TAG = "placeName";
    private static final String LONGITUDE_TAG = "lng";
    private static final String LATITUDE_TAG = "lat";
    // private static final String ADMIN_NAME_TAG = "adminCode3";
    private static final String POSTAL_CODE_TAG = "postalcode";
    private static final String POSTALCODE = "postalcodes";

    // ***from JsonHandlerClass****//

    JSONParserHandler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new HTTPGetTask().execute();

    }

    private class HTTPGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

        private static final String USER_NAME = "devleb";

        private static final String URL = "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username="
                + USER_NAME;

        AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);

            JSONParserHandler responseHandler = new JSONParserHandler();
            try {

                return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (null != mClient) {

                mClient.close();

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        JsonActivityHttpClient.this, R.layout.list_item, result));

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.json_activity_http_client, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {

            //String item = (String)l.getItemAtPosition(position);


        //  PostalCodes.get(position);


            String  PLACENAME = postalCode.get(PLACE_NAME_TAG).toString();
            String  LATITUDE = postalCode.get(LATITUDE_TAG).toString();
            String  LONGITUDE = postalCode.get(LONGITUDE_TAG).toString();
            String  POSTALCODE = postalCode.get(POSTAL_CODE_TAG).toString();



  Log.e("position of the Item in the list", "you select the item number " + PostalCodes.getString(position));

            Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Row_Item.class);
            in.putExtra("placename", PLACENAME);
            in.putExtra("lat",  LATITUDE);
            in.putExtra("lng", LONGITUDE);
            in.putExtra("postaCode", POSTALCODE);
            startActivity(in);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Error in the onListItemClick",
                    "LOOK AT THE onListItemClick method");
        }

    }

    // *************JSONParserHandler*******************************//

    private class JSONParserHandler implements ResponseHandler<List<String>> {
        /*
         * private static final String PLACE_NAME_TAG = "placeName"; private
         * static final String LONGITUDE_TAG = "lng"; private static final
         * String LATITUDE_TAG = "lat"; private static final String
         * ADMIN_NAME_TAG = "adminCode3"; private static final String
         * POSTAL_CODE_TAG = "postalcode"; private static final String
         * POSTALCODE = "postalcodes";
         */
        @Override
        public List<String> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            result = new ArrayList<String>();
            String JSONResponse = new BasicResponseHandler()
                    .handleResponse(response);

            try {

                jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(JSONResponse)
                        .nextValue();

                PostalCodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray(POSTALCODE);

                for (int i = 0; i < PostalCodes.length(); i++) {
                 postalCode = (JSONObject) PostalCodes.get(i);

                    result.add(postalCode.get(PLACE_NAME_TAG) + "\n"
                            + POSTAL_CODE_TAG + ":"
                            + postalCode.get(POSTAL_CODE_TAG) + LATITUDE_TAG
                            + ":" + postalCode.get(LATITUDE_TAG) + "\n"
                            + LONGITUDE_TAG + ":"
                            + postalCode.get(LONGITUDE_TAG));
                }
            } catch (JSONException E) {
                E.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    // *************JSONParserHandler*******************************//

}
```

i think the problem is in this method

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {

            //String item = (String)l.getItemAtPosition(position);


        //  PostalCodes.get(position);


            String  PLACENAME = postalCode.get(PLACE_NAME_TAG).toString();
            String  LATITUDE = postalCode.get(LATITUDE_TAG).toString();
            String  LONGITUDE = postalCode.get(LONGITUDE_TAG).toString();
            String  POSTALCODE = postalCode.get(POSTAL_CODE_TAG).toString();



  Log.e("position of the Item in the list", "you select the item number " + PostalCodes.getString(position));

            Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Row_Item.class);
            in.putExtra("placename", PLACENAME);
            in.putExtra("lat",  LATITUDE);
            in.putExtra("lng", LONGITUDE);
            in.putExtra("postaCode", POSTALCODE);
            startActivity(in);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Error in the onListItemClick",
                    "LOOK AT THE onListItemClick method");
        }
```

## Row_Item

```
package com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Row_Item extends Activity {

    TextView Place_Name, txtlat, txtlng, txtPostalCode;

    String value1, value2, value3, value4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_row__item);

        Place_Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtlat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLAT);
        txtlng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLNG);
        txtPostalCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPSTC);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (null != i) {
            value1 = i.getStringExtra("placename");
            value2 = i.getStringExtra("lat");
            value3 = i.getStringExtra("lng");
            value4 = i.getStringExtra("postaCode");
        }
        Place_Name.setText(value1);
        txtlat.setText(value2);
        txtlng.setText(value3);
        txtPostalCode.setText(value4);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.row__item, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that you don't specify which of those objects to choose so it apparently chose the last. On the second look, when you parse the json document you left the last object in postalCode variable (method handleRespone() ). That's the cause. What you could do is to reparse the specified postal code or save all postal codes in an array and use them in OnListItemClick() method.

Comment: @ WrongASP  what do you mean **reparse the specified postal code or save all postal codes in an array and use them in OnListItemClick() method.**  can you help me ??

Comment: You can either do reparse: postalCode = (JSONObject) PostalCodes.get(position); directly in OnListItemClick() or when you parse the json document (in handleResponse() ) you can save all parsed postalCodes in an array and use the one you need (accessed by index) in OnListItemClick(). Hope this helps.

Comment: so i initialize new JSONObject  in the onListItemClick method where i is the position of the Item then how to use this new jsonobject ??

Comment: thank you fro your help but i have a question why it must be reparsed ??

Comment: You don't have to change the rest of the method.For the second comment, it doesn't really need to.But to avoid that you need the data saved after the first parsing.And because you don't know which one you will need, you need to save them all in a variable. You have actually done that too, but not in the ideal format. Look at the variable result. It has all the data, but to get them you would need to parse the string. What I'm proposing is to use data from result if you don't need to separate values or create another variable to coexist with result and store the data in more appropriate format.